# how to get data from parse json_encode to ajax jquery

Tags: php, ajax, codeigniter, json

```
//this is views file in codeigniter
$(".saving").click(function(){
    var id_member = $("#code_member").val();
    $.ajax({
        url     : '<?=site_url();?>show_joinmember/',
        type    : 'post',
        dataType: "json",
        data    : {'id_member':id_member},
        success : function(data){                           
            alert(data);
        }
    });
});



function show_joinmember(){
    $id  = $this->input->post('id_member');
    $qry = "select * from member where id_member = $id";
    $Sql = $this->db->query($qry)->result();
    foreach ($Sql as $r){
        $r->value  = $r->vendor_acct;
        $r->id     = $r->apinvoice_id;
        $row_set[] = $r;        
    }
    echo json_encode($row_set); 
}
```

result alert(data)

> [object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object
>   Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object
>   Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object
>   Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object
>   Object],[object Object]

Comment: instead of `alert(data)` use `console.log(data)`; you will see the result; and if you want to parse use `for .. in` loop

Comment: You need an array instead of an object so use `$Sql = $this->db->query($qry)->result_array();`, then just `echo json_encode($Sql);`

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/jquery.parsejson/

Answer (score 0):

use `result_array()` instead of `result()`
in

```
$this->db->query($qry)->result();
```

like this

```
$Sql = $this->db->query($qry)->result_array();
    foreach ($Sql as $r){
        $r['value']  = $r['vendor_acct'];
        $r['id']     = $r['apinvoice_id'];
        $row_set[] = $r;        
    }
 echo json_encode($row_set);
```

Comment: i have try it but result same